# Как установить анимацию AnimateCSS, которая будет срабатывать каждый раз когда нажимаем на лайк

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, dom, css-animation

```js
var likes = 0;
var num = document.getElementById('numero');

function pulse() {
  num.setAttribute("class", 'animated  pulse');
}

function counter() {
  likes++;
  num.innerHTML = likes;
  pulse();
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" id="btn" onclick="counter()"></div>
</a>
<div id="numero"></div>

</body>
```

Анимация срабатывает только один раз при нажатии на сердечко, я пробовал повторным переопределением класса на пустой класс и затем, снова на класс с анимацией, но почему-то не получилось. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: У вас код не работает.

Comment: Я понимаю что он не работает. Тут нужно AnimateCSS подключать и bootstrap. Мне нужно логику понять, а не код запускать.

Comment: На сколько понял что требуется - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/womzeY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var likes = 0;
var num = document.getElementById('numero');

function pulse() {
  num.setAttribute("class", 'animated  pulse');
  setTimeout(function(){
    num.setAttribute("class", '');
  }, 1000);
}

function counter() {
  likes++;
  num.innerHTML = likes;
  pulse();
}
```